# flat approximation of a circle at a point

Tags: circles

I need to find a flat approximation of a circle at a given point.  The circle I am working with is $$x^2+y^2=\frac9 4$$

The point is $(1,\sqrt{\frac 5 4})$

I have found an approximation, but it is not flat.  Here is what I did:

$$\left( y = \sqrt{\frac 9 4 -x^2})\right)\lor \left( y = -\sqrt{\frac 9 4 -x^2})\right) $$

The derivative of the top half of the graph gives me $$ y = - \frac{x}{\sqrt{
\frac 9 4}- x^2}  $$

Using function transformation, I got 
$$ y = - \frac{x-1}{\sqrt{\frac 9 4 - (x-1)^2}}
+\sqrt{\frac 5 4} $$

Which looks like a good approximation, but again, it is not flat.

Comment: what do you menas exactly for ''flat''? ifyou menas linear approximation use the tangent line.

Comment: ok.  That makes sense.  I think I forgot how to do some stuff from calculus.

Comment: You need to evaluate the derivative at $x = 1$ to get the numerical slope of the tangent line. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Note that your circle is centered at the origin. The tanget at a point is orthogonal to the radius so if the coordinate of the point are $(1, \sqrt{5/4})$ the slope of the tangent is $-\dfrac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}$ and the equation of the tangent line is:
$$
y-\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2}=-\dfrac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}(x-1)
$$